# Multiple tweets using PHP and TwitterOAuth

Tags: php, twitter

i'm looking for a way to tweet messages (maximum of 10) using 4 different accounts. I was able to do so using abraham's class, but after a few tweets, i keep getting 403 status codes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to the number of tweets you can make per hour.  How many you can make depends on how you are using the API.  See http://support.twitter.com/entries/160385-how-do-i-get-whitelisted